# How do I get the Flurry achievement?

Tags: defense-grid-awakening

In Defense Grid: The Awakening, what level and tower build order/strategy will allow me to easily get the Flurry achievement, which requires me to get a gold medal on an adrenaline challenge mode?

Comment: You better be prepared to nominate someone for a serious bounty if they give you an entire tower build order...

Comment: @bwarner If they did that I would give it to them myself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Basics

- Map: Ancient Research
- My Points: 120k
- Needed Points: 100k
- Lasertower into cannon into motar & temporal

#### Build order:

- Build 3 green laser tower spaced out (bottom left, bottom middle, top left)
- Update when needed
- Build 5 cannon tower button left once the shielded enemies come
- Upgrade them pretty fast

You should have +50k money by now and getting **massive** interest.

Add some temporal (bottom middle and top left and middle) and motar tower (right middle and top right) where needed and end with ~50k money

#### My this works out:

Laser towers are **extremely** effective and **cost efficient** against the types of enemies that map.

You can get up to a lot of money very quickly as you need very view tower and `"interest snowball"` from there.

---

Small screenshot to show this off. The three laser towers that get you through the first 10 rounds are already placed.

[image: Initial placement]

Comment: I may try this out later, I don't use laser towers much but this looks like a good candidate to try.

Comment: Thanks, I pretty much did what you described but it took a little trial and error to figure out which towers to upgrade/build when.

Comment: I just tried this out but by about wave 26 I'm starting to get overwhelmed, and that's with adding in some temporal towers and some extra laser towers. Would be nice to add tips for what to add and where at this stage.

Answer (score 10):

I did it on the map called Ancient Research since its the earliest map with an adrenaline mode.

I started out upgrading the little maze area in the northern corner with a flame turret in the middle and a gun turret next to it.  Don't upgrade them until round 1 (for interest) and then bring them both to yellow.  After that, sit on interest until you see enemies start to reach the core, then place a gun turret next to the other 2 and upgrade that.

The next area to focus on is the cluster of 4 closest to the core. I put a temporal and command tower there along with a meteor and cannon.  You'll need that command tower as later missions involve stealthed units.  Putting it earlier also gives you a little credit boost if you upgrade its coverage area.

Once those are all nice and upgraded, just start spreading out with more gun, meteor, and cannons and you'll be fine.

Here is my final layout:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I didn't use your build order, but your little tower configuration at the top left was pretty helpful for the cloaked waves.

Comment: I tried out your solution as well as edorian's, and found yours a lot easier. By round 26 or so I had red towers everywhere and after that I could just hold down "f" until the game was over (ended with 124k points). Nice and easy! Only differences I had from your build was that I swapped your gun tower in the lower right area with a temporal tower, and your extra inferno in the lower left was a cannon for me.

Comment: Combing this strategy with the laser in the corners netted me a score of over 150K

Answer (score 4):

I did this on the map: Standing Order

Notes About Adrenaline Mode: When I first read this, I thought it meant the waves happened closer and closer together. That isn't true. What *actually* happens is that the enemies base speed gets faster and faster.

This means you want towers that can deal their damage quickly, and with a pretty sizeable range. This means Cannon and Meteor Towers.

[image]

I started in the lower righthand corner of the map, first mazing with gun towers, and getting the command tower to level 3 ASAP. I had this setup by about wave 15, and spent the next 35 waves alternatively mashing F and upgrading towers.

[image]

Level 3 command towers give you a huge boost to your salvaged resources (and consequently, your points). At the end of the game, Interest alone was giving me ~400 resources each tick. And those points add up fast!

[image]

When you're allowed to sit back and collect interest for 35 waves... the score gets very massive, very quick.

Answer (score 3):

go to the third story level, and pick adrenaline.  You should only need to build gun, laser, inferno, and temporal towers.  Start with the first build area on the path, build 4 guns and 1 laser turret leaving one spot blank for a temporal later.  Upgrade only when you need to hoarding your money to maximize interest.  At the second build position I like ot put one laser and three guns. I skip the third one leaving it for last, and build an inferno tower on the corner with gun towers around it (may want a temporal tower here).  Always remember to build or upgrade at the last possible minute, and upgrade before building more if you can. Any spaces I didn't mention should be fully upgraded gun towers around wave 25.  Doing this I got a score of 147736 when the medal only requires 100000.

Just saw the post above mine. Great guide, I should mention that command and meteror towers are almost never worth they're cost though.  Most levels can be done with only gun and cannon towers for damage, with maybe a laser tower for faster enemies and a temporal tower at choke points.  This reduces tower cost and increases score (less spent => more hoarded => more interest).

Comment: @Kummlekar I agree meteor towers are expensive, but when you ball them up with temporal towers their splash can really boost their value/damage ratio.  If you had unlimited space, guns and cannons win out every time, but with limited space like this map you want the most bang for the least amount of space so I went with more flames and meteor towers.  You make some good points overall though.  Oh, and welcome to the site.

Answer (score 0):

I placed the corner build down first them the lasers and update the lasers when I went up to 2K then I placed down the 3 guns(Far Right) after that when I went up to 5k then I then added into the top left a metor cannon and finally a temporal. in the bottom left I had the normal laser in the same place then a metor temporal and a flamer just to keep things rolling I ended up with 120K. 8D